# How to convert sklearn logistic regression to PMML scorecard model

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pmml

I'm trying to convert a scorecard model in python into a [PMML scorecard model](http://dmg.org/pmml/v4-1/Scorecard.html).

I have trained a sklearn logistic regression using binned training data. Now I have the trained LR model(or a pipeline containing LR), the binning information which includes binning labels and WOEs, and pre-established offset and factor. I am able to sklearn2PMML the pipeline into PMML but what if I want a PMML scorecard model which can output scores directly instead of probabilities?

Is there any possible approaches to do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to develop a library/tool, which reorganizes a binary classification-type `RegressionModel` or `GeneralRegressionModel` model into a regression-type`Scorecard` model; WOEs and other supplementary information to the process would be provided using an external settings/configuration file.

Alternatively, you might try subclassing your LR estimator class, and keep the supplementary information there. The [SkLearn2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml) package can be extended for custom transformer and estimator types using the [SkLearn2PMML-Plugin](https://github.com/jpmml/sklearn2pmml-plugin) approach.

The [R2PMML](https://github.com/jpmml/r2pmml) package provides a way to transform `glm` objects to `r2pmml::scorecard` objects, which can be then converted to `Scorecard` models.